# how can I get all possible subgroups in python regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to get all possible subgroups during regex findall: `(group(subgroup))+`. Currently it only returns the last matches, for example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'SOME_STRING_(([A-D])[0-9]+)+_[A-Z]+', 'SOME_STRING_A2B2C3_OTK')
[('C3', 'C')]
```

Now I have to do that in two steps:

```
>>> match = re.match(r'SOME_STRING_(([A-D][0-9]+)+)_[A-Z]+', 'SOME_STRING_A2B2C3_OTK')
>>> re.findall(r'([A-D])[0-9]+', match.group(1))
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Is there any method can let me get the same result in a single step?

Comment: AFAIK, your two-step example is the best way. The reason the first example returns only C3 is that `findall` returns all non-overlapping matches.

Comment: Is `['A', 'B', 'C']` your desired output?

Comment: It would make it easier for the reader if you were to begin by stating the rules (in words) for extracting the information of interest from the string.

Comment: You could roll your own incremental finder using [`re.iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer). I think the `(..)+` syntax does not play nicely with `group` but I can't find a reference to that.

Comment: Do you have any data like `SOME_STRING_A10E50_OTK` which contains alphabets outside [A-D] in the "alphabet + digit(s)" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `(([A-D])[0-9]+)+` is a [*repeated capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), it is no wonder only the last match results are returned.

You may use a [PyPi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (that you may install by typing `pip install regex` in the console/terminal and pressing ENTER) and then use:

```
import regex

results = regex.finditer(r'SOME_STRING_(([A-D])[0-9]+)+_[A-Z]+', 'SOME_STRING_A2B2C3_OTK')
print( [zip(x.captures(1),x.captures(2))  for x in results] )
# => [[('A2', 'A'), ('B2', 'B'), ('C3', 'C')]]
```

The `match.captures` property keeps track of all captures.

If you can only use `re`, you need to first extract all your matches, and then run a second regex on them to extract the parts you need:

```
import re
tmp = re.findall(r'SOME_STRING_((?:[A-D][0-9]+)+)_[A-Z]+', 'SOME_STRING_A2B2C3_OTK')
results = []
for m in tmp:
    results.append(re.findall(r'(([A-D])[0-9]+)', m))
print( results )
# => [[('A2', 'A'), ('B2', 'B'), ('C3', 'C')]]
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/EJYVK52861)

Answer (score 0):

A single-regex (and possibly single-pass-of-data) solution can be done, provided your sample code and sample data are both well-defined. The assumed premises are:

1. **The length of `SOME_STRING_` is fixed**. This is based on the example data you give, where `SOME_STRING_` reads a literal string and not a regex.
2. **The data contains no `[E-Z]` or other exceptions in its "alphabet-digits" part**. This is based on your working 2-lined solution, which should have returned an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` if data like `SOME_STRING_A1B2Z3_OTK` exists. However, the error was not reported, so I assume you did not have such data.

If the above are met, a single regex `r"[0-9]+"` can be used to perform a straightforward string split. All digits are discarded because [the `+` operator is greedy according to the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). The greedy match could be theoretically done with a single pass of data, so the efficiency should be satisfying if it is indeed the case. (I did not have a check on the implementation details though.)

**Solution**

```
import re    
s = 'SOME_STRING_A10B20C30_OTK'  # len("SOME_STRING_") = 12 is fixed
                                 # may have multiple digits in between

re.compile(r"[0-9]+").split(s[12:])[:-1]  # discard the last element
# returns ['A', 'B', 'C']
```